# Refining broad, primitive types into enum types in Flow

Tags: flowtype

I'm writing a function that accepts a string, and if the string value is a member of an enum, I'd like to treat it like the type I've defined for that enum. A simplified example:

```
const FRUITS = Object.freeze({
  APPLE: 'APPLE',
  BANANA: 'BANANA',
});

type Fruit = $Values<typeof FRUITS>

function fruitChecker(input: string) {
  if (Object.values(FRUITS).includes(input)) {
    (input: Fruit);
  }
}
```

[Example in Flow's web editor](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAxnAdgZwC5gBiASgKoCSAKgMpgC8YA8gEYBWApungHRQBO7dgC92ACgDeqMGACCABTkAZAKIAuMAHJ5S5RoA0UsACEZAOTMz1Gk+fP7UAXwCUAblSo8ATwAO7InwBXAEsCBgASADUAQxgA9hwAHi9fOCgiMipqAD53KACsLiDsMH5gvABhAAtOAGt2PlEgrG8AvHV8PiaAcycwSWkgtNEWDi5uADcYuJxREgoaJ24m9FiAE3jG5tanXv7pME2Wtv8y10MHRyA)

Flow throws an error saying my input in that conditional is not a Fruit. But how can my input not be a Fruit as I've defined it? Is there a right way to perform operations on an enum member after refining the input from a broader, primitive type?

Comment: Funny that the following works `const t: Fruit = "APPLE";` but the casting doesn't work. Maybe a bug within flow. As a workaround you can cast it to any before casting it to the Fruit type. `((input: any): Fruit)`

Comment: There is an opened issue about `Object.values` flow annotation: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:
https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6904 and
https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2221

So `.includes` can't be used for refinement, and `Object.values` returns `mixed`. This means that the scenario you are trying is not currently possible.